# java android inserting blob and strings with special chars using raw query - sqlite3

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm writing application for which I would like to have two versions - one for desktop (java standard edition) and one for android.

Currently I'm working on database model. In order to have code working in both version, the first idea was to skip all those functions which are incompatible between two platforms (unfortunately Android and desktop Java have fully different classes for managing SQLite databases even if some methods are similar) and to use only pure raw SQL statement.

However when going deeper, I have many problems with this approach.

1) How to store BLOB using pure raw SQL statement (something like

```
insert into table (col1, col2) values (val1, [...... 100KB val 2])
```

There are many answers how to do this ex. using ContentValues class for Android, but then either I would have to create my own set of classes covering standard Android/desktop Java classes either to make this database layer in two separate versions.

2) How to replace in automatic way all those chars which have special meaning for sql statement, ex. "father's car" - ' is not allowed to be put directly in sql statement (please dont forget just pure raw sql statements).

Concluding:

A) Do you know answer on my questions above?
B) Is that worth to work in that way (only pure raw sql statements)?
C) If not what approach to admit - create my own set of class for manipulation, or simply create two different versions of this database layer?

Btw, I can understand that Android has fully different classes for GUI, but why they created fully different approach for such things like databases....

Answer (score 0):

1. In SQLite, you can use [blob literals](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#litvalue):

```sql
    INSERT INTO Tab(blob) VALUES(x'001122abcdef');
```

1. *All* SQL APIs allow to use parameters; in the Android SQLite API, even `rawQuery` has this:

   ```
   db.rawQuery("INSERT INTO Sold(ID, Name) VALUES(1234, ?)",
               new String[] { "father's car" });
   ```

Comment: How to convert ex. image file to blob literal?

Comment: Thanks a lot. However I'm still wondering if the approach to have only raw sql statement is a good idea. Perhaps it will have so significant influence on efficiency and will complicate many things (ex. if I use Android executeInsert I can get id of the newly added record, while when using pure raw sql statement, I will not get it. In consequence I have to ask the database for it, ex. basing on unique name).